# How to make the responsible image align center in mobile site?

Tags: html, css, wap

I've got 4 images for the wap site.
When in small screen, I want it will be two lines,two images per line.
If in big screen that like ipad,then it will become 4 images one line.
And is also align center in the page, how can it be?

it's my html part here:

```
<div class="fo3">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/pic1.jpg" width="100%" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/pic2.jpg" width="100%" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/pic3.jpg" width="100%" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/pic4.jpg" width="100%" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

this is css part:

```
.fo3{
    padding:0 10%;
    max-width:80%;
}

.fo3 ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
}

.fo3 ul li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    max-width:268px;
    display:inline;
}

.fo3 ul li img{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: maybe i made a mistake,it's a website that mobile phone can browse,not wap...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check out [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries)? They allow you to define different css styles based on the [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#width) of the user's screen, among other things.